# SQL query that returns aggregate AND non aggregate results

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I need to write a query that returns both aggregate and non-aggregate data from a table.

The example below, should help clarify what I'm trying to do. I have the following (simplified) tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE course_group_def (
          id        PRIMARY SERIAL KEY,
          name      TEXT NOT NULL
          );

CREATE TABLE student (
          id        PRIMARY SERIAL KEY,
          grp_id    INTEGER REFERENCES course_group_def(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          name      TEXT NOT NULL,
          weight    float NOT NULL,
          height    float NOT NULL
          );
```

For the sake of argument, lets assume that each student belongs to one and only course group. I want to write a query that will return a result set like this:

student.name, student.weight, weight_apgaw, weight_apgh

**Where:**

**weight_apgaw:** is the weight of the individual student, expressed as a percentage of the average weight of the course group he/she belongs to.

**weight_apgh:** 
is the weight of the individual student, expressed as a percentage of the average height of the course group he/she belongs to

I have NO idea (well some idea) about how to go about writing such a query. My approach would be to write two queries, and somehow do a lookup between the two tables - but such an approach seems nonsensical and inefficient at best.

Could someone please suggest how I may correctly write such an SQL function?. Ideally, this should be db agnostic. However, I am using PostgreSQL 8.4, so if I have to choose between SQL flavours, this takes precedence.

Comment: weight_apgh - individual **weight** expressed as a percentage of average **height**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a query along these lines should get you started:

```
select s.name
     , s.weight
     , ((s.weight/st.avgweight) * 100) as weight_apgaw
     , ((s.height/st.avgheight) * 100) as weight_aphei
from student s 
join (
   select grp_id
        , avg(weight) as avgweight
        , avg(height) as avgheight
   from student
   group by grp_id
   ) st on s.grp_id = st.grp_id
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) - like so:

```
select name,
       weight,
       height,
       100 * weight / avg(weight) over (partition by grp_id) weight_apgaw,
       100 * weight / avg(height) over (partition by grp_id) weight_apgh
from student
```