# An SQL query that combines aggregate and non-aggregate values in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query gives me the information that I need but I want it to take it just a step further. In the table at the bottom (only showing a subset of the fields), I want to group by cust_line in an unusual way (at least to me it's unusual).

Let's look at the items with a cust_line of 2 as an example. I would like these to be represented by one line not 5. For this line, I would like to select all the fields except for the price field where the cust_part = "GROUPINVC". For the total field I would like it to be 'sum(total) as new_total' and for the price, I would like it to be new_total / qty_invoiced, where qty_invoiced is the value on the line where cust_part = "GROUPINV".

Is what I am asking for completely ridiculous? Is it even possible? I'm not advanced at SQL so it may also be easy and I just don't know how to approach it. I thought of using 'partition by' but I couldn't imagine how I would get it to work as I figured it would still return 5 rows where I only want 1.

I've also looked at these questions with similar titles but not really what I am looking for:

[SQL query that returns aggregate AND non aggregate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878402/sql-query-that-returns-aggregate-and-non-aggregate-results)

[Combined aggregated and non-aggregate query in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531560/combined-aggregated-and-non-aggregate-query-in-sql)

```
SELECT L.CUST_LINE, I.LINE_NO, I.ORDER_NO, I.STAGE, I.ORDER_LINE_POS, I.CUST_PART, 
I.LINE_ITEM_NO, I.QTY_INVOICED, I.CUST_DESC, I.DESCRIPTION, I.SALE_UNIT_PRICE, I.PRICE_TOTAL,
I.INVOICE_NO, I.CUSTOMER_PO_NO, I.ORDER_NO, I.CUSTOMER_NO, I.CATALOG_DESC, I.ORDER_LINE_NOTES
FROM 
  (SELECT CUST_LINE, ORDER_NO, LINE_NO
   FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE
   GROUP BY CUST_LINE, ORDER_NO, LINE_NO
   ) L
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ORDER_IVC_REP I
ON I.ORDER_NO = L.ORDER_NO
WHERE RESULT_KEY = 999999
AND I.LINE_NO = L.LINE_NO
ORDER BY L.CUST_LINE;

| cust_line | line_no | cust_part | qty_invoiced | cust_desc | price | total |
|         1 |       4 |      ...  |            1 |       ... |    55 |   55  |
|         2 |       1 | GROUPINV  |            1 | some part |     0 |    0  |
|         2 |       6 |      ...  |            3 |       ... |     0 |    0  |
|         2 |       2 |      ...  |            1 |       ... |     0 |    0  |
|         2 |       3 |      ...  |            1 |       ... |     0 |    0  |
|         2 |       7 |      ...  |            2 |       ... |    10 |   20  |
|         3 |       7 |      ...  |            1 |       ... |    67 |   67  |
```

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question

Comment: I'm using an Oracle database so I thought that may sway the answers one way or the other.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: PL/SQL is not "Oracle's version of SQL", although many people seem to think so.  PL/SQL is a procedure language specific to Oracle, which can include SQL statements.  PL/SQL could be a solution to your problem (although it's not the only one), but what you have shown in your query is simply SQL.  You are right that what RDBMS you are using is important.

Comment: Okay, I will remove PL/SQL from the title. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an analytic function to calculate a total over multiple rows of a result set, then filter out the rows you don't want.

Leaving out all the extra columns for sake of brevity:

```
SELECT cust_line, qty_invoiced, order_total/qty_invoiced AS price
FROM (
  SELECT l.cust_line, qty_invoiced,
    SUM(total) OVER (PARTITION BY l.cust_line) AS order_total,
    COUNT(cust_line) OVER (PARTITION BY l.cust_line) AS group_count
  FROM
  (SELECT CUST_LINE, ORDER_NO, LINE_NO
   FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE
   GROUP BY CUST_LINE, ORDER_NO, LINE_NO
   ) L
  INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ORDER_IVC_REP I
  ON I.ORDER_NO = L.ORDER_NO
  WHERE RESULT_KEY = 999999
  AND I.LINE_NO = L.LINE_NO
)
WHERE ( cust_part = 'GROUPINV' OR group_count = 1 )
ORDER BY cust_line
```

I am guessing on what you want in the `PARTITION BY` clause; this is essentially a `GROUP BY` that applies only to the `SUM` function.  Not sure if you might also want `order_no` in the partition.

The trick is to select all the rows in the inner query, applying SUM across them all; then filter out the rows you are not interested in in the outermost query.

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm. I had to add a couple things to it though. The where clause filters out everything except for the 'grouped' row so I added count(cust_line) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_line) AS group_count and then in my WHERE clase I added 'OR group_count = 1. I wouldn't mind if you modified your answer to reflect this for the benefit of future viewers. Thanks again!

Comment: One weird thing though. When I added the other partition to my select statement, oracle sql developer underlined it with an orange squiggly saying that "SELECT list inconsistent with GROUP BY" and suggested that I add all the non-calculated items to my group by clause. Query works fine though and we're using a partition not a group by. I've never had much faith in the syntax highlighting for oracle sql developer (this coming from a guy who's only been using it for a week).

Comment: Glad it helped.  Edited the answer per your comment - I think I captured it correctly.  You are quite right about SQL Developer; its syntax rules are incomplete.  Even some keywords aren't recognized as such.